# Chrome Extension not triggered on Google Calendar page (<all_url> in manifest.json)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first Chrome extension and it currently appears to work on all sites that I have tested apart from Google Calendar (which is really where I would like it!)

I've simplified the code as much as possible to try and fix this;

manifest.json:

```
      {
    "name": "TestExtension!",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Quick Test Extension",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
  }
```

content.js

```
console.log("Chrome extension go...");
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgtLE.png)

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM9KG.png)

Any ideas? What is different about Google Calendar. It works fine on Gmail and I have tried specifying the Calendar URL specifically as well with the same results.

Comment: Sounds like your domain administrator restricted that URL via [runtime_blocked_hosts](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/extension-settings-full).

Comment: I am the domain admin (this is currently running on my home lab). I don't remember setting any policies and Chrome is stating 'No Policies Set'

Comment: Works4me. Make sure you've reloaded the tab.

Comment: Thanks all! - I had reloaded the tab, killed Chrome and reloaded but noticed a second extension that I had installed wasn't working on the calendar tab either. A full restart (and Windows update) later and it's all working perfectly! Cheers all, really appreciate the second pairs of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to wOxxOm - A full Windows restart fixed the issue. (I really should have tried that, still not sure why killing all the Chrome processes didn't work but sorted now)